# Is it safe to use multiple symbols hits per row in the Aster nPath algorithm?

Tags: teradata, teradata-aster

On page 77 of the Aster Analtyics users guide:
http://www.info.teradata.com/eDownload.cfm?itemid=122580002

it says:
“Note that the predicates for different symbols may overlap, and therefore multiple symbols may match the same row.”

Does anyone have any experience with practical use cases where you actually need multiple symbols per row?

Concern is this could explode pretty quickly:  for n symbols per row and m rows in a partition, number of symbol combinations per partition is n^m.
e.g., for n=2 and m=50 this results in ~1e15 symbol combinations which we certainly don't want to traverse.

Thx,
Francis

Answer (score 0):

nPath in Aster will never match multiple symbols per row, but multiple symbols may match the same row and nPath will have to choose one of them when forming its result. There will be many cases when this is possible, for example, when you have general page hit (defined as TRUE) and then special pages like START, FINISH, BASKET, etc. then the matching will depend on how pattern is defined.